# JSON string to String Array

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `JSON String` returned by Google Places API which somewhat looks like this:

```
{ "html_attributions" : [], "next_page_token" : "CvQB7AAAAKInrUGS9TZSaskfjkajsfY2CL5gnlli8FaXClYCOfnt6CpDZtSJanUx0OtgZPdXKw9ILf9fqNW1T29gc3mXRZPBKhujEN20qrtYfdfhPubbEHYv6UpKjasf;laskfl;kaTHq1O81Lpr2AwwxlrAX92bKxyky2kXzsVnuUJGO63R58SpEoVOxqMUBvVpxiYljeoRS93VfTib7iaNvwT3JmDeZJMt16b7ID2RUc-OmfjDmJZbikwaaBR_DKlHLjm1FmCvSoUwPQrKp5Lgm0S_pCI6OCnnFnWckYVRIQrkJ4xOC6eVLWVEG16MZmoRoUyWNAKcK6-b6PdLMQQoEY04MSG_o", "results" : [ { "geometry" : { "location" : { "lat" : 94.8793165, "lng" : 17.1700843 }, "viewport" : { "northeast" : { "lat" : 94.8848793, "lng" : 17.1755888 }, "southwest" : { "lat" : 94.8734316, "lng" : 77.1650671 } } }, "icon"
```

I want to convert this JSON string into more usable type ideally like `string[]`.
I tried

```
 var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 string[] arr = serializer.Deserialize(result,string[]);
```

But I am aunable to get the second argument to `Deserialize` right.
Please help me out with this.

Comment: Instead of `string[]` try `typeof(string[])` as the second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Your JSON is in the wrong format. If you're using the demo response to test, it's not formatted properly.

Here is a modified version in the correct format

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "next_page_token": "CpQCAgEAAFxg8o-eU7_uKn7Yqjana-HQIx1hr5BrT4zBaEko29ANsXtp9mrqN0yrKWhf-y2PUpHRLQb1GT-mtxNcXou8TwkXhi1Jbk-ReY7oulyuvKSQrw1lgJElggGlo0d6indiH1U-tDwquw4tU_UXoQ_sj8OBo8XBUuWjuuFShqmLMP-0W59Vr6CaXdLrF8M3wFR4dUUhSf5UC4QCLaOMVP92lyh0OdtF_m_9Dt7lz-Wniod9zDrHeDsz_by570K3jL1VuDKTl_U1cJ0mzz_zDHGfOUf7VU1kVIs1WnM9SGvnm8YZURLTtMLMWx8-doGUE56Af_VfKjGDYW361OOIj9GmkyCFtaoCmTMIr5kgyeUSnB-IEhDlzujVrV6O9Mt7N4DagR6RGhT3g1viYLS4kO5YindU6dm3GIof1Q",
    "results": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": -33.867217,
                    "lng": 151.195939
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
            "id": "7eaf747a3f6dc078868cd65efc8d3bc62fff77d7",
            "name": "Biaggio Cafe - Pyrmont",
            "opening_hours": {
                "open_now": true
            },
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 600,
                    "html_attributions": [],
                    "photo_reference": "CnRnAAAAmWmj0BqA0Jorm1_vjAvx1n6c7ZNBxyY-U9x99-oNyOxvMjDlo2npJzyIq7c3EK1YyoNXdMFDcRPzwLJtBzXAwCUFDGo_RtLRGBPJTA2CoerPdC5yvT2SjfDwH4bFf5MrznB0_YWa4Y2Qo7ABtAxgeBIQv46sGBwVNJQDI36Wd3PFYBoUTlVXa0wn-zRITjGp0zLEBh8oIBE",
                    "width": 900
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJIfBAsjeuEmsRdgu9Pl1Ps48",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "price_level": 1,
            "rating": 3.4,
            "reference": "CoQBeAAAAGu0wNJjuZ40DMrRe3mpn7fhlfIK1mf_ce5hgkhfM79u-lqy0G2mnmcueTq2JGWu9wsgS1ctZDHTY_pcqFFJyQNV2P-kdhoRIeYRHeDfbWtIwr3RgFf2zzFBXHgNjSq-PSzX_OU6OT2_3dzdhhpV-bPezomtrarW4DsGl9uh773yEhDJT6R3V8Fyvl_xeE761DTCGhT1jJ3floFI5_c-bHgGLVwH1g-cbQ",
            "types": [
                "cafe",
                "bar",
                "restaurant",
                "food",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont"
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": -33.866786,
                    "lng": 151.195633
                }
            },
            "icon": "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
            "id": "3ef986cd56bb3408bc1cf394f3dad9657c1d30f6",
            "name": "Doltone House",
            "photos": [
                {
                    "height": 1260,
                    "html_attributions": [
                        "From a Google User"
                    ],
                    "photo_reference": "CnRwAAAAeM-aLqAm573T44qnNe8bGMkr_BOh1MOVQaA9CCggqtTwuGD1rjsviMyueX_G4-mabgH41Vpr8L27sh-VfZZ8TNCI4FyBiGk0P4fPxjb5Z1LrBZScYzM1glRxR-YjeHd2PWVEqB9cKZB349QqQveJLRIQYKq2PNlOM0toJocR5b_oYRoUYIipdBjMfdUyJN4MZUmhCsTMQwg",
                    "width": 1890
                }
            ],
            "place_id": "ChIJ5xQ7szeuEmsRs6Kj7YFZE9k",
            "scope": "GOOGLE",
            "reference": "CnRvAAAA22k1PAGyDxAgHZk6ErHh_h_mLUK_8XNFLvixPJHXRbCzg-gw1ZxdqUwA_8EseDuEZKolBs82orIQH4m6-afDZV9VcpggokHD9x7HdMi9TnJDmGb9Bdh8f-Od4DK0fASNBL7Me3CsAWkUMWhlNQNYExIQ05W7VbxDTQe2Kh9TiL840hoUZfiO0q2HgDHSUyRdvTQx5Rs2SBU",
            "types": [
                "food",
                "establishment"
            ],
            "vicinity": "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont"
        },
        {
            "aspects": [
                {
                    "rating": 23,
                    "type": "overall"
                }
            ],
            "status": "OK"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'd suggest, is using a website like [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to create C# classes from that response, and manipulate the data as needed.

Comment: this return an empty array.

Comment: please update the JSON string in your OP. It appears that not all of it is included. Also, this doesn't appear to be a true string array. You might need to deserialize it to an object, and then take the data you want from it. This JSON appears to have multiple levels, therefore won't deserialize into a simple string[]

Comment: you can view the returned Google Pleaces API `JSON` [here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchPaging)

Comment: Please see my edit. You will need more than just a string array to handle this.